# Divide N floats into M groups so that the sum of each group is as equal as possible?

Tags: optimization

Given a list of N non-negative real numbers:

t = [2.99, 7.9, 24.58, ..., 3.1415, 40.4]

I want to partition the elements of $t$ into $M$ groups, $g_1$, $g_2$, ..., $g_M$, so that the sum of each group is as close as possible to $sum(t)/M$, i.e. minimizing the root mean square error:

**Minimize**: $\sqrt{\Sigma_i^M (sum(g_i) - sum(t)/M)^2 }$.

Do anyone know a close-to-optimal algorithm of doing this generally? Or do anyone know the name of this problem? (My google-fu failed me).

**Background**: $t$ represents time in seconds to run $N$ different tasks, and I want to schedule the $N$ tasks on $M$ different computers in such a way that all computers finish their tasks at the same time (or as close as possible).

Comment: Wouldn't your intended application suggest to minimize $\max_i\sum(g_i)$ instead?

Comment: This looks like a variant on the [bin packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) problem to me.  It is known to be NP-hard in the general case, but there are approaches that are pretty good.

Comment: Can you confirm that $M$ is imposed ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, M is fix, for example "5", and not subject to change.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Good point, yes, minimizing your expression is also interesting. And now I'm curious if the optimal solution to that will automatically also be the optimal solution for the RMSE.

Comment: For minimizing the maximum time, search for *makespan*.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ M \leq N $. I try to reply to your question in terms of a problem of optimization attributable to a **Boolean linear programming problem**. You need $ m \cdot n $ Boolean variables to trace the assignment of task to computer: $ x_{i,j} $ is a Boolean variable whose value is 1 if i-th task is assigned to j-th computer, zero otherwise.

The objective function can be properly formulated as

$ \min \sum_{j,k=1}^m | g_j – g_k | $

where $ |.| $ is the absolute value.

Constraints:

$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\sum_{j=1}^m x_{i,j} = 1 \forall i=1, \cdots , n \\
x_{ij} \in \left \{ 0 ; 1 \right \} \forall i,j \\
\end{array} \right. $

where

$ g_j = \sum_{i,j=1}^n t_i \cdot x_{i,j} $ is the service time for j-th computer

$ \sum_{j=1}^m x_{i,j} = 1 $ requires that i-th task is assigned to one and only one computer

$ x_{i,j} $ is a Boolean variable whose value is 1 if i-th task is assigned to j-th computer,  0 otherwise.

By means of $z_1, \cdots , z_m$ real variables,  the problem can be formulated as a **linear** programming model.

$ \min \sum_{j=1}^m  z_j $

subject to

$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\sum_{j=1}^m x_{i,j} = 1 \forall i=1, \cdots , n \\
g_j – g_k \leq z_j \forall j,k=1, \cdots , m \\
g_j – g_k \geq - z_j \forall j,k=1, \cdots , m \\
x_{ij} \in \left \{ 0 ; 1 \right \} \forall i,j \\
\end{array} \right. $